# Rails path variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, link-to

If I have the following route in my Rails routes.rb file:

```
get "time_track/check_in"
```

What will the path variable be that I can use in my views? I assumed something like `time_track_check_in_path` or `check_in_time_track_path`. However, neither of those work:

```
<%= link_to 'Check-in', check_in_time_track_path %>
<%= link_to 'Check-in', time_track_check_in_path %>
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` say about it?

Comment: it should be the second one, what error do you get?

Comment: I must've made a mistake somehwere, @Zippie, you're correct. @slhck, that helped confirm to me it was `time_track_check_in_path` so I tried it again and it worked... I must've typed it wrong at first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When providing a verb route the `RouteSet` will make a best guess as to the controller/action and helper method name. It does require at least 2 segments in the matching path, otherwise you have to supply the controller, action and helper name yourself.

For a single segment matcher (no slashes in the path) the full definition is required.

```
# Looks for FooController#index and provides foo_path/foo_url
get 'foo', :to => 'foo#index', :as => :foo
```

For a matcher with two or more segments it will assume the following syntax.

```
# Looks for FooController#bar and provides foo_bar_path/foo_bar_url
get 'foo/bar'
# Looks for Baz::FooController#bar and provides baz_foo_bar_path/baz_foo_bar_url
get 'baz/foo/bar'
```

One thing to note is that this behavior is different from the resources matcher in regards to the path helper name. Using this syntax provides namespace_controller_action where using resources and namespaces provides action_namespace_controller, which may be where some of your confusion between the two formats lies.

For example if you had a time track resource already then you would add it like so:

```
# Provides /time_track/check_in as check_in_time_track_path mapping to TimeTrackController#check_in
resources :time_track do
  collection do
    get :check_in
  end
end
```